# Clickhouse after reload

Tags: clickhouse

In our clickhouse were queried alter table delete from orders..
and clickhouse after killing him by OOM, reload and write in logs errors like this:

```
default.orders::202008_87744_112785_8339_964654} <Error> virtual bool DB::MutatePlainMergeTreeTask::executeStep(): Code: 241. DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 10.80 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4243232 bytes), maximum: 10.80 GiB. (MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):`

`0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0xb4903fa in /usr/bin/clickhouse`
`1. DB::Exception::Exception<char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(int, fmt::v8::basic_format_string<char, fmt::v8::type_identity<char const*>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<char const*>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<long&>::type, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::type>, char const*&&, char const*&&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&) @ 0xb4a8843 in /usr/bin/clickhouse`<br><br>

and more<br>
```

Maybe it's those alter table requests run after reload?

What can I do about this problem?

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

i had too many mutation
After the reboot, they started up and filled all the memory
I kill all mutations for my table with the command: 
`KILL MUTATION WHERE database = 'default' AND table = 'orders'`
After this command, all mutations were removed and database freed memory